# Is it possible to limit the number of messages a user can send a day with Django postman?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have been using Django Postman for a few weeks now, and in order to limit the number of messages sent by each user, I have been wondering **what would be the best way to limit the number of messages a user can send a day, a week... using Django-postman**?

I have been browsing dedicated documentation for weeks too in order to find an answer for the *how*, but I think this is not a usecase for now, and I do not really know how to manage that.

Of course I am not looking for a well cooked answer, but I would like to avoid writing labyrinthine code, so maybe just a few ideas about it could help me to see clear through that problematic.

Many thanks for your help on that topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to my own question.

After a lot of research and hours of unsuccessful tests, I found a way to do so (while this is not integrated in django-postman app itself). Actually it may sounds basic for a lot of people, but nevermind I am still going to share my solution, which relies on `decorators`.

At first I tried to create my own `ReplyView`, but it was a lot of pain to make it work with django postman: I did not succeed, so if someone knows how to do that I would appreciate to read him/her/apache.

Also, please notice I did everything I did in order not to edit Django postman code (as my modifications would be crushed by any Django Postman update).

---

### 1. Creating your custom `decorator`

In your `decorators.py` file (that you have to create if you don't have one), you have to create the `decorator` you will use to decorate default Postman `ReplyView`. I will assume you associated a `profile` model to user, as it is your profile that will memorize the number of messages sent a day, and a `canSendMessage` method that will check if connected user is allowed to send a new message (returns `True` if user quota is reached).

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def count_messages_sent():
    def decorator_fun(func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            user_profile = request.user.profile

            # we check if user is allowed to send a new message
            if not user_profile.canSendMessage(): 
                messages.error(request, "Messages limit reached")
                return redirect('postman:inbox')

            # if he is, we call expected view, and update number of messages sent
            called_func = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            user_profile.nbr_messages_sent_today += 1
            user_profile.save()

            return called_func
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator_fun
```

---

### 2. Using your custom `decorator`

As I said before:

- I do not want to edit original postman code,
- I do not want to create custom views.

So, we will have to decorate Django Postman `ReplyView`! How? Through your app `urls.py` file:

```
from postman import views as postman_views
from yourApp.decorators import count_messages_sent

urlpatterns = [
    ... 
    url(r'^messages/reply/(?P<message_id>[\d]+)/$', count_messages_sent()(postman_views.ReplyView.as_view()), name='custom_reply'),
]
```

---

### And that's it! It works like a charm.

*If you have any idea of improvement, please do not hesitate to share!*

Answer (score 1):

as a simple idea the  inserting of new msg in database should be with a condition to limit their numbers (the count of the previous msg  isn't > max )
 another method : you will show the input of the msg jsut when  (selet * form table where userid=sesion and count(usermsg)< max )

Comment: I think I would not get what I want that way, still I agree with you with the idea to control manually the number of sent messages. Actually I am going to try to override `postman views`, also I will create new attributes in my user `profile` model, and this is where I am going to count that. I will post what I did here if it works!